# how to remove "public" in url subproject codeigniter 4

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have projectA and projectB in code igniter 4.3.2. projectB in projectA. when I use localhost/projectA/projectB/public/home ,that working to call controller default projectB, but when I remove "public" in url  its not work. url "localhost/projectA/projectB/home" call controller default in projectA. I have .httaccess in root projectA like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

what must i do?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really recommended by CI for security reasons. If you want to omit the *public* from your URL, you can configure your web server to point to the *public* directory instead of the project root.

However, if you really want to remove the public directory, you should make sure you have moved the index.php one level up. In terms of .htaccess, you can use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also, in index.php you need to remove the `../` from require command that loads *app/Config/Paths.php* .